# Sonoma Time Machine Issue - hangs when attempting to set up new volume

Tags: time-machine, sonoma

I just upgraded PB M1 Max to Sonoma and attempted to set up a new volume for Time Machine. The volume is a stripe of 2 2TB drives on a serial ATA interface, running off Akitio converter with SoftRaid. Another set of 2 2TB drives in the same enclosure is running with Time Machine just fine. Trouble starts after I set up the stripe and format to HFS+, then go to Time Machine and attempt to add the new volume. The new volume hangs with "Preparing XXX"... dialog. I waited over six hours, no dice. The dialog has a cancel button, but it does nothing when pressed. Get a beep when I try to quit System Settings, and the only way to quit is through Force Quit. When I crash out and restart, the volume shows up as "EFI" with a tiny size, so it is useless. I tried deleting the volume, re-formatting, and setting up TM several times, but every time it's a hang with the progress bar stuck right in the middle.

Comment: tbh, I know nothing about the RAID issue, but TM doesn't use HFS+ any more, it uses APFS. Also make sure you're using GUID beneath that - new drives tend to arrive formatted MBR/ExFAT. It probably won't let you format MBR/APFS, but it will let you use MBR/HFS+ if you're not careful.